# Verification of proof for bijective mapping from a subgroup $H$ to a coset $aH$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Recently I have been reading about groups from Michael Artin's Algebra. There I read a statement that there always is a bijective map from a subgroup $H$ to a coset $aH$. As to why there exists such a bijective map, no proof was given. Injectivity is quite obvious.

Here I have tried to come up with a proof for surjectivity and wanted to verify it.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ where $H=\{h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_n\}$

Let $aH$ be a left coset of $H$ for $a\in G$ and let $h_x$ be an arbitary element of $H$

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$,
$$h_x\in G$$
$$\Rightarrow h^{-1}_x\in G$$
$$a\in G$$
$$\Rightarrow ah^{-1}_x\in G$$
Now let $ah^{-1}_x=b$
$$ah^{-1}_xh_x=bh_x$$
$$a=bh_x$$
$\therefore b\in aH$

Now as $h_x$ was an arbitary element of $H$, for every $h_x\in H$, there exist a $b\in G$ such that $a=bh_x$

**$\therefore aH$ contains as many elements as in $H$. Now as there is an injective mapping from $H$ to $aH$, the same mapping must be surjective.**

Please verify this proof and offer suggestions or alternate methods for this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is okay, but I don't see the need for the subscript $x$ for your element of $H$. It's also too long.

---

*Here's the nub of the argument . . .*

The bijection is 
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_a: H&\to aH,\\
h&\mapsto ah
\end{align}$$

with inverse

$$\begin{align}
\lambda^{-1}_a: aH&\to H,\\
k&\mapsto a^{-1}k.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for verification, is there any other alternate proof you can provide?

Comment: You're welcome, @DevanshKamra. Simply compose $\lambda_a$ with $\lambda_a^{-1}$ both ways, to show that $$\lambda_a\circ\lambda_a^{-1}={\rm id}_{aH}$$ and $$\lambda_a^{-1}\circ\lambda_a={\rm id}_{H}.$$ That is sufficient for $\lambda_a$ to be a bijection between $H$ and $aH$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks a lot.